# How to display two tooltips with different css parameters when hovering a single element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am want to display 2 tooltips, next to each other.

```
<a href="#" class="tooltips">
    <img src="images/MyImage" />
    <span>
My first tooltip info displayed at the top side of my image.
</span>
</a>
```

That is how my tooltip is made. 
It is displayed when hovering over an `image`.
I want to display a second tooltip on the left side.

I am using different `css` style which display it on the left side but I don't know how to combine them together.
I need this for my game I am working on in javascript/html.

**Note:** There might be a time when I want to display only 1 tooltip.
It is supposed to "compare" two of player items.

@Edit:
Here is jsfiddle example: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nw1yx2rc/3/)

Comment: Can you please provide you code in fiddle.

Comment: Hey, I added example in my post. I hope it will be helpful.

Comment: It would be helpful if you had an image of what this is *supposed* to look like. But if you want another tooltip, use a second span and just position it too one side.

Comment: my css is like : a.span  
which means that if I create a second span inside <a href=""> tag it will be positioned same way, but I will try to add a class or something and see if it works. I am still not experienced with css so I will have to try it :)  
Also I want a second span to be displayed on the left of the first span, so they are next to each other, but not on top of each other. Well I will probably add a class to my span and change some values, hopefully it will work out.